# Returned JSON string from JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, regex, json, web-services, javascriptserializer

This is my server-side C# code.

```
JavaScriptSerializer jsSer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

string strJson = jsSer.Serialize(tableData); \\tableData is List type
string strRawJson = Regex.Replace(strJson, "\\s{2,}", ""); \\ Remove Whitespaces
```

This is value of strRawJson that I am getting now.

```
"[{\"RowNumber\":1, ... , "ActivityDate\":\"\\/Date(1378310400000)\\/\",\"ErrMessage\":null}]"
```

Here is my **first question**.

I would like to see the value of 'ActivityDate' as this format: '2013-10-24 12:00:00:000'. How can I do? 
 PLEASE NOTE that I want to do this in **C# (NOT JAVASCRIPT)**, also I don't want to use **JSON.NET**

Here is my **second question**

As you can see my third line of code, I used Regex to remove some whitespaces. Is there another possible error when I generate JSON via JavaScriptSerializer?

Thank you very much in advance! :)

**[Edit]**
I understand that JavascriptSerializer is very limited, but can I still get some help for my 'second' question, please? or Recommend another good serializer?

Comment: Why don't you just turn ActivityDate into a string in your required format?

Comment: `JavaScriptSerializer` is very limited.  If it does exactly what you want, it's great.  If you want it to do something different, you're screwed.  Despite your objections, you should use a different serializer such as json.net.  Finally, the fact that you are using a regex at the end to get rid of whitespace should be a clue that you are not using an ideal serializer.

Comment: @Kirk Woll This is my webservice(.asmx), and I need to serialize myList to JSON string. If then, which serializer do you recommend? hmm.. I didn't know that JavaScriptSerializer is very limited..

Comment: Json.Net is supported by the microsoft web API these days too so it's not as if it's a fly by night 3rd party component that's just going to disappear any minute.

Comment: @Liam my JSON string would be super long, I don't think it is easy to do with string.replace thing..

Comment: @Liam oh JSON.NET is not a 3rd party resource??

Comment: This [blog by hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx) goes into details. See *"We on the web team will be including JSON.NET as the default JSON Serializer in Web API when it releases, so that'll be nice."*

Comment: It is 3rd party, but microsoft are starting to use it themselves because they realise that it's a better option than the inbuilt one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you use MVC.net? If so, you can use this method of the controller:

```
protected internal JsonResult Json(object data, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
{
  return this.Json(data, (string) null, (Encoding) null, behavior);
}
```

if you call your action, you will receive the plain json formatted string.

You can use string.Format() to format your date or just do it within js.

Comment: Just what serializer do you suppose MVC is using to serialize the json?   (hint, it's `JavaScriptSerializer`)  Given that, how does your answer address the OP's question at all?